# jQuery ajax token refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This input has a random token value and it changes when the page refresh. How can I trigger this php code which is in the input value with jQuery ajax? I can't refresh all of the page. I must only refresh this input.

İnput:

```
<input id="token" type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::change(); ?>">
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: just try to store token using php session or cookie if you do not want to change it when refreshing a page via jQuery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval` to call a `php method using $.ajax` and get the response `<?php echo Token::change(); ?>` on each call and update the value of the field in `success` part:

```
$("#token").val(data);//here data is the echo/return value from your php function whill will be value of Token::change().
```